# Doesn't see the Spring MVC mapping java

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-mvc, controller

Hey I have an ajax request that is called when i press a button, but the servlet mapping doesn't work. It is not going to the controller when i press the button.
This is the script that makes the ajax request to the controller.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function getData() {
        var dataToBeSent = {
            uName : $("#jsonResponse").text() //
        }; 

        $.ajax({
            url : 'something/testing', // Your Servlet mapping or JSP(not suggested)
            data : dataToBeSent,
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'html', // Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.
            success : function(response) {
                $('#outputDiv').html(response); // create an empty div in your page with some id
            },
            error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }; 


</script>
```

The #jsonResponse is a

that is allocated dynamically first.
This is the controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/something")
public class Test {

    @RequestMapping("/testing")
    public void test(@RequestBody String yey){

    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/api?user=root&password=1234");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String query = "INSERT INTO test(Id, nume) value (default, ?)";
    PreparedStatement preparedStmt;
    try {
        preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStmt.setString (1, yey);
        preparedStmt.execute();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(yey);        
}
}
```

Comment: do you have a 404 error? the server is reached? do you have some errors in the js console?

Comment: @MohamedBathaoui Yes i have this error POST localhost:8080/ApiAi/something/testing 404 ()

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your servlet, you forgot to set the POST or GET method types, which your servlet should listen for. in you ajax you sent a POST request, but no where in your servlet you are mentioning the type of the request

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/something/testing", method = POST)
```

I think that this might work for you

Comment: I put @RequestMapping(value = "/something/testing", method = RequestMethod.POST) but it gave me the same error POST localhost:8080/ApiAi/something/testing 404 ()

Comment: so your server routers are prefixed with ApiAI, try accessing it through  localhost:8080/something/testing , did you intentionally prefixed it with ApiAi ?, can you paste the content of application.properties in src/main/resources ?

Comment: It gave me 404 when I try accessing like this localhost:8080/something/testing because all my pages are prefixed with ApiAi (which is the name of the project)

Comment: then why don't you specify it on your ajax tcall o be url : 'ApiAi/something/testing'

Comment: POST http://localhost:8080/ApiAi/ApiAi/something/testing 500 () the ajax dosn't go to the controller

Comment: actually 500 means that it went to to controller but there is an internal server error , it means that something is wrong inside your controller itself. is there any data with the response ? can you replace the requestmapping to the initial state     @RequestMapping("/testing")
 and test again, is your server logging any information related to that error ?